# how to sequence number sub gorups

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table structure like below

```
id  wstage      wstatus wdate
101 Unaquired   create  2013-08-29 17:07:20.040
101 Unaquired   rework  2013-08-29 18:07:20.040
101 inprocess   accqui  2013-08-29 19:07:20.040
101 inprocess   alloca  2013-08-29 20:07:20.040
101 Unaquired   create  2013-08-29 21:07:20.040
101 Unaquired   rework  2013-08-29 22:07:20.040
```

I have to number this like

```
id  wstage      wstatus wdate                   rownumber
101 Unaquired   rework  2013-08-29 22:07:20.040 1
101 Unaquired   create  2013-08-29 21:07:20.040 1
101 inprocess   alloca  2013-08-29 20:07:20.040 2
101 inprocess   accqui  2013-08-29 19:07:20.040 2
101 Unaquired   rework  2013-08-29 18:07:20.040 3
101 Unaquired   create  2013-08-29 17:07:20.040 3
```

I am trying to use function

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id,wstage order by wdate desc) rownumber
```

but this is not giving desired output. I dont want to use pl/sql is there a ranking function or simple query to achive this. my table has 50 million records.

Comment: In 2012, you could use the `ROWS` feature. In 2008, it has to be a more complex query. For best efficiency, perhaps a cursor.

Comment: There is no logic in your result set. Why two last rows have `rownumber = 3` ?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev 'rownumber' is in decending order of 'wdate'. for change in 'wstage' 'rownumber' should incerement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `wdate` values are unique per `id`, this might do the job:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id         ORDER BY wdate DESC)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, wstage ORDER BY wdate DESC)
  FROM atable
),
maxdates AS (
  SELECT
    id, wstage, wstatus, wdate,
    maxwdate = MAX(wdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id, wstage, grp)
  FROM partitioned
)
SELECT
  id, wstage, wstatus, wdate,
  rownumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY maxwdate DESC)
FROM maxdates
;
```

The first CTE determines distinct `id, wstage` islands, the second one finds maximum `wdate` per island, and the main query ranks the rows based on the found maximum values.

A SQL Fiddle demo [is available](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e5a5/1) for this query.